# How to implement Reflectly like color (theme) changing ui like below?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, slider, user-experience

I liked the reflecty wave-like theme colour changer a lot. was trying to build that whole section but how the theme changer section is done, is on my mind. I am a newbie in the flutter.

what I was able to implement is page controller and vertical scroll on it.

but stuck with this.

[image]

like how is the wave pattern list was made?

Answer (score 0):

late answer. I have created a wave animation no reflectly like but should do the trick.find a [complete gist here](https://gist.github.com/ggichure/2b6f804f10f228f1cd834a5ba024979f).run it on dart pad to see results.

here is the code for creating the animation

```
return AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: _controller,
              builder: (context, child) {
                var page = pageList[index];
                var delta;
                var y = 1.0;

                if (_controller.position.haveDimensions) {
                  delta = _controller.page - index;
                  y = 1 - delta.abs().clamp(0.0, 1.0);
                }
```

[image: as shown]

Comment: this is close but I am more curious about the wave pattern in the select colour buttons. still will definitely give it a try. and thank you for your post :)